# I want to get a Java dev internship with no prior cs background and with the help of a technical project to present, I'm not sure of my chances

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, internship

I obtained my licence in economics but without pursuing because it became obvious I wouldn’t get the career path I wanted so I decided to switch to software development. During my bachelor courses, I had some in MySQL, Python and web development but nothing extraordinary.  I’m planning on putting the chances to my side with a presentation of a project I would develop in Java. I will recreate Flappy Bird but I don’t know If that might be perceived badly because It’s not an original creation or even if that can be taken seriously for a technical project.

The goal with this presentation is to demonstrate the things I learned by developing a game and to have something valuable to add for the interview as I don’t have much experience in programming. For information, this internship is half time in the company and the other half is spent with the online courses with Open Classrooms which you may have heard about.

Also, as I like exploring the technical side of cryptocurrencies like how blockchains works; I do that by curiosity and for investing in projects that are relevant with what I’m looking for, I can probably mention that when we will get to the center of interests in the interview. So, my question is there a better technical project that I could prepare ? What would be the requirements for a good technical project at my level ? I live in France if it might be of any relevance.

Answer (score 4):

Do not worry about doing something that has been done before. It's actually a good idea to do that. Because once you're finished with it, you can usually find the code of those other similar projects and see how your code compares to theirs.

> So, my question is there a better technical project that I could prepare ?

Probably, but do not let that stop you.

For instance, if you're going to apply to a company which makes business applications, then having a business application in your portfolio would be preferable.

With that said, don't let that stop you from working on such a project. Flappy birds won't be your first project, nor will it be your last.

Comment: Thank you for the tips !